# How to get a System's total CPU usage percentage of a remote computer using a java program or JMX

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, cpu-usage

Hi in my system there will be a master node and n number of slave nodes. The master node will forward the incoming request to one of its slave nodes. I want to find the CPU usage of all its slave node, So that i can forward the request to the appropriate node. I have found similar question like this in that they answered to use getCpuUsage() to find. But when i use it am getting an error like cannot find symbol: getCpuUsage(). Can any one please suggest me how can i find the cpu usage percentage (of the slave node with their i.p address). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I used this snipped of code to compute cpu load with java 1.5 extracted from jconsole:

```
public class CPULoad {

      private static long prevUpTime, prevProcessCpuTime;

      private static RuntimeMXBean rmBean;        

      private static com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean sunOSMBean;

      private static Result result;

      private static class Result {
        long upTime = -1L;
        long processCpuTime = -1L;
        float cpuUsage = 0;
                int nCPUs;    
      }

      static{
       try {
        rmBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();                              
        //reperisco l'MBean relativo al sunOS
        sunOSMBean  = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(
                    ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(), 
                        ManagementFactory.OPERATING_SYSTEM_MXBEAN_NAME,
                    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.class
                );           

       result = new Result();
       result.nCPUs = sunOSMBean.getAvailableProcessors();
       result.upTime = rmBean.getUptime();
       result.processCpuTime = sunOSMBean.getProcessCpuTime();

       }catch(Exception e){
          System.err.println(CPULoad.class.getSimpleName()+" exception: "+e.getMessage());          
       }
  }


  public CPULoad(){ }


  public float getCPULoad(){

    result.upTime = rmBean.getUptime();
    result.processCpuTime = sunOSMBean.getProcessCpuTime();

   if(result.upTime > 0L && result.processCpuTime >= 0L) 
         updateCPUInfo();

    return result.cpuUsage;

   }

  public void updateCPUInfo() {
    if (prevUpTime > 0L && result.upTime > prevUpTime) {
        // elapsedCpu is in ns and elapsedTime is in ms.
        long elapsedCpu = result.processCpuTime - prevProcessCpuTime;
        long elapsedTime = result.upTime - prevUpTime;
        // cpuUsage could go higher than 100% because elapsedTime
        // and elapsedCpu are not fetched simultaneously. Limit to
        // 99% to avoid Plotter showing a scale from 0% to 200%.
        result.cpuUsage =
            Math.round(
                Math.min(100F,
                        elapsedCpu / (elapsedTime * 10000F * result.nCPUs) 
                        ) 
                    );                      
    }

    prevUpTime = result.upTime;
    prevProcessCpuTime = result.processCpuTime; 
 }

  }
```

Comment: This does not really compute the cpu load. It only counts the time the cpu is busy with the current Java process, but not with any other processes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. But this seems to find the cpu load on the current machine. But how to find the cpu load of the slave node, which will be connected in the network. Is it possible to find the cpu load of the slave node via remote access..?